# Sieve of Eratosthenes using list of booleans

Tags: python, boolean, sieve-of-eratosthenes

OK I am trying to make a sieve of Eratosthenes. I originally used this code.

```
def shake(n):
    n == 2                  # initializes 2 since it's first prime
    prime = []              # makes empty list
    for i in range(2, n+1): # takes range from 2 to N
        if i not in prime:  
            print (i)
            for i in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                prime.append(i)

shake(100)
```

It does print off a list, but I was told I did it wrong. I was told I need to pass in a list of booleans, and return a list of prime numbers. The logic is I make a list of booleans from an input of length N. I made figured out how to make a list booleans with this

```
def shake(alist)
    N = 10
    alist = [True for _ in range(N + 1)]
```

and if I use a print it gives me this.

```
[True True True True True True True True True True True]
```

I need to be able to turn the first two values of true to false, then leave the value of the third 'true' as true but turn all multiples of two to false, then do the same logic for 3, 5,7, etc. until I exhaust the list. Then I need to be able to be able to somehow scan it for remaining true values and print a list off of those numbers as my prime numbers. I really lost because I don't know how to change the values of my list of 'True' to false, and how to do it in a loop and how I know when to stop. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Aw man, prime sieves! This is how I learned to program in python! Here is a simple one:

```
def primes(n):
"""Finds all the primes less than n."""
    #First build your list of Trues
    ps = [1] * n
    #next, set the first two entries to False
    ps[0]=0; ps[1]=1
    #i is the index, p_i is the primality value.
    #the int(n**0.5) part makes us only look at the numbers less than the square
    #root of n.
    for i, p_i in enumerate(ps[:int(n**0.5)]):
        #if p_i is True then i is prime
        if p_i:
            #mark off every ith number from i^2 as nonprime
            for j in xrange(i*i, n, i):
                ps[j]=0
    #return every index that has the value True
    return [i for (i, p_i) in enumerate(ps) if p_i]
```

[image: Sieve of Eratosthenes]

You have a list of numbers which are all marked as prime. You take the first number n, and, starting from its square, you mark off every nth number as non-prime (a.k.a composite.) When n is greater than the square root of the largest number in the list, you stop. Every number still marked as prime is prime!

It is possible to skip the even numbers when you build your list and sieve, but that is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to use in Project Euler problems that might be a little clearer than Broseph's solution and accumulates the primes as it goes (if you are using python3 change xrange -> range).

```
primes(maxp):
    """
    Returns a list of all primes < maxp.
    """
    sieve = [True for x in xrange(maxp)]
    prime_lst = [1]
    for i in xrange(2, int(sqrt(maxp))):
        if sieve[i]:
            prime_lst.append(i)
            for j in xrange(2*i, maxp, i):
                sieve[j] = False
    return prime_lst
```

Comment: I have a question, I cant import math, is there a way to handle this without doing that?

Comment: `def sqrt(n):return n**0.5`